# Intercept ajax requests with jquery to display BlockUI

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, blockui

i'm trying to intercept ajax requests with jquery, to display a waiting message like with using plugin BlockUI, but how can i intercept requests sended by the UpdatePanel provided from asp.net framework, is some way to take the trigger?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *beginRequest* and *endRequest* client side events of the PageRequestManager to display a "please wait" UI.

`Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.instance.add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandler)`

`Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.instance.add_endRequest(endRequestHandler)`

See [here](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/ClientReference/Sys.WebForms/PageRequestManagerClass/b865e12a-caf3-4cfd-8878-fafc0bd8b70c.aspx) for more information. There are examples for each event.

Comment: Thanks for you guys, all two has fast anwsers :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what an UpdatePanel is, but *generally* you could use the [ajax global events](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events) for that, e.g.:

```
$(document).bind("ajaxStart", function() {
    $.blockUI();
}).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
    $.unblockUI();
});
```

If you have ajax calls *outside* of the UpdatePanel that you do not want to block the interface, you would need to set the `ajax` option:

```
global: false,
```

to ensure that they are excluded.